How to Send Authentication Token from Frontend using Both Fetch & Ajax to Restful API Backend?
I am currently working with django restframwork, I am on my training period. I created a api for lottery management system using DRF and in this restful api i added IsAuthenticated permission class. Now i am creating demo project for this api, now i am using ajax for requests & sending authorization using btoa. but i am sure that this is not a professional method. I wanted to learn how to send the authorization token to backend with username and password. & also how to achieve same in reactjs as i am little bit familiar with react js and working on it as well.

function ajaxCall(type, url, data, callback) {
  /**Common Method to handle all the Ajax Requests */
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(xhr);
      if (xhr.status != 204) {
        if (callback) {
          callback(response);
        }
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.error("Error occurred:", xhr.responseText, status, error);
    },
  });
}


To send an authentication token from the frontend to a RESTful API backend using both Fetch and Ajax, you can follow the steps below.
Using Fetch API
// Assuming the token is stored in localStorage after login
const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

fetch('https://api.example.com/endpoint', {
    method: 'GET', // or 'POST', 'PUT', etc.
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, // Structure depends on your API
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

Using jQuery Ajax
// Assuming the token is stored in localStorage after login
const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.example.com/endpoint',
    type: 'GET', // or 'POST', 'PUT', etc.
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` // Structure depends on your API
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error:', errorThrown);
    }
});

I hope this example code helped you. :)

Can you Provide me a Sample Response of Login API

That doesn't address secure storage practices. You should mention avoiding localStorage for sensitive data due to potential XSS vulnerabilities. And please keep in mind that AI generated answers will not be tolerated on Stack Overflow.

{
"success": true,
"data": {
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC91Ym9cL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNzI5NTE0NTY2LCJleHAiOjE3Mjk3MzA1NjYsIm5iZiI6MTcyOTUxNDU2NiwianRpIjoicWpOR2JudjZWOTh1TVo3bCIsInN1YiI6MzYxMiwicHJ2IjoiYjkxMjc5OTc4ZjExYWE3YmM1NjcwNDg3ZmZmMDFlMjI4MjUzZmU0OCJ9.rDb-CQuOv1jetEvpx8KURi3_Linvf05u2yu58EJNfTI",
}
}

Above is the example response of login api
